# Limit argument types for guard function

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typeguards

How to implement a guard function `isUndefined` that only accept arguments whose type includes `undefined`? The function should assert that the argument is `undefined`.

Basic implementation:

```
function isUndefined(value: unknown): value is undefined {
  return typeof value === 'undefined';
}
```

The expected behavior:

```
isUndefined(true) // <- Compilation error. argument type does not include undefined

const arg = true as boolean | undefined
isUndefined(arg) // <- No error. Argument type includes undefined.
// Compiler infers arg as undefined
arg // Hover arg in IDE => arg: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a `isUndefined` function that behaves similarly to what you described. In your "expected" example, you do nothing with the result of the call `isUndefined(arg)` so the last value would never be inferred to be `arg: undefined`. I will assume that this is just a mistake.

**The problem**

The function you are describing is supposed to be able to take a value that is a union that **has to** contain `undefined`. This is not a common thing in typescript. As you may know typescript has generic functions, and you can restrict the parameters of generic functions using the `extends` keyword. This is a basic example:

```js
function fn<T extends number>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}

fn(1 as number | string); // Errors
```

In this case, the function will accept anything that is at least number. Meaning that the call with `number | string` will error.

However this is not what we are looking for. We need some sort of a constraint that will mean: "There has to be a possibility that the argument passed in will be `undefined`".

**The solution**

In typescript this is achieved by flipping the extends constraint. This is a basic example:

```js
type Test<T> = undefined extends T ? true : false;

type A = Test<1>;
//   ^? type A = false

type B = Test<1 | undefined>;
//   ^? type B = true
```

Of course, we cannot just do this in the generic type constraint for a function. However, we can use a little trick and use a helper generic parameter to get the result.

This is a working example:

```js
function isUndefined<T extends R, R = undefined extends T ? T : never>(
  value: T,
// @ts-ignore
): value is undefined {
  return value === undefined;
}

isUndefined(true); // Errors

const arg = true as boolean | undefined;
if (isUndefined(arg)) {
  console.log(arg);
  //          ^? const arg: undefined
} else {
  console.log(arg);
  //          ^? const arg: boolean
}
```

[TSPlayground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgVTAEwKbBmbTAHgBVFsAPKbLFRAJQBoHEBeRcHPAzcqmzHTIB%20RGQBciAgDdsAJwB8ACgBQiRNICGAGxDZJJRioD0xxAAEoKALQwA5mDhzsKgJSStu7Mjqdc%20QkQAbzVEZygQOSRPPTZWdj9uQgBuFQBfFRVUDC4AzCUoOT1XVJUIBBQoRE05OzZEQtjNOgAjODhtbE0kAB8OLH8eVJhgRCVsgaT8mrtXV2DQ8rAUDuwAOm04OyUZktDTdUOjxAA9YXTybRRvEPUllc6NrZ3avfUD46Oz9MygA)

The function is little involved so let's go over it.
We cannot flip the generic constrait directly in the parameter, so we are using a helper generic parameter `R` which as you can see is not constraint in any way. If we try to constraint it like this `..., R extends T | never ...` we would get a circular reference error.

As you can see though, the `R` parameter is being assigned a default value. In the value assignment, we can use the above mentioned technique, to set `R` to eigher `T` if `undefined` is present in `T` or `never` otherwise.

We can then use this value of `R` to constraint `T`.

This does not error, because values are being set before the constraits are checked.

**Why the @ts-ignore**

Typescript tries to enforce that the type specified in the `value is undefined` declaration (in our case `undefined`) is even possible to be passed in to this function. However, due to the complex nature of our type definition, and `R` not being constraint (which means that the caller could theoretically supply their own type for `R` which would allow them to pass in a value which can never be undefined) typescript throws an error.

We cannot do something like `isUndefined(value: T | undefined)` because that would break the inference of `T`.

So as developers, we tell typescript to ignore the error, because we know better. And this is not a problem, because even if someone provided their own types, they would only get the ability to check if some value is undefined or not.

This is a walkthrough:

**Example 1**

Let's say we are passing in a value of `boolean | undefined`

Firstly, values are assigned. `T` is assigned a value of `boolean | undefined` (inferred from the argument) and `R` is assigned a value of `T` because `undefined extends T`.

After that constraints are being checked. `T` is supposed to extend `R` which is equal to `T`, therefore `T` is supposed to extend `T` which is valid.

Everything works!

**Example 2**

Let's say we are passing in a value of `boolean`

Firstly, values are assigned. `T` is assigned a value of `boolean` (inferred from the argument) and `R` is assigned a value of `never` because `undefined` doesn't extend `boolean`.

After that constraints are being checked. `T` is supposed to extend `R` which is equal to `never`, therefore the constraint for `T` fails.

Everything works!

**Note**

The error procuded by this solution can be quite cryptic for someone who doesn't understand typescript very well, therefore I would suggest putting a JS Doc comment on the function explaining the `is not assignable to never` error.

Even better solution might be replacing the `never` type with something like `"The value passed in must have a chance of being undefined"`. This would also work, and the resulting error message would be as follows:

> Argument of type `true` is not assignable to parameter of type `"The value passed in must have a chance of being undefined"`

**Modified version**

```js
function isUndefined<
  T extends R,
  R = undefined extends T
    ? T
    : "The value passed in must have a chance of being undefined",
>(
  value: T,
  // @ts-ignore
): value is undefined {
  return value === undefined;
}
```