# Mapped Types for a dynamic generic value in Typescript

Tags: typescript-generics

Given the below interface

```
interface FooValue<A,B> {
  mainKey: string;
  first: A;
  second: B;
}
```

I want to create an object where the key is the "mainKey" and the value is the above object itself.

```
eg:
const input = {
  key1: {first: "text1", second: 1, mainKey: "key1"},
  key2: {first: 2, second: "text2", mainKey: "key2"},
};


function acceptInput(input: /*map of key and FooValue where key is the value of `mainKey`*/){
 return input;
}
```

What I have tried and is not working:

```
interface FooValue<A,B> {
  mainKey: string;
  first: A;
  second: B;
}


type FooValueObj = {
  [key: string]: FooValue<unknown, unknown>
};

type FooConfig<T extends FooValueObj> = {
  [Key in keyof T as T[Key]['mainKey']]: T[Key]
};


function acceptInput<T extends FooValueObj>(foo: FooConfig<T>) {
  return foo;
}

const x = acceptInput({
  key1: {first: "text1", second: 1, mainKey: "key1"}, // here TS should check that the "key1" and the value of mainKey should be same.
  key2: {first: 2, second: "text2", mainKey: "key2"},
});

x.key1.first // typescript is showing type of `first` is showing as `unknown`, it should ideally be string.

x.key2.first // typescript is showing type of `first` is showing as `unknown`, it should ideally be number.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

I found even better solution than the previous two

- It has very good error messages in every case
- Doesn't require `as const` in the function argument

```js
interface FooValue<A, B, Key = string> {
  mainKey: Key;
  first: A;
  second: B;
}

// Map over T if for a given key K => K != T[K].mainKey
// replace that value with "object key and value of mainKey must be equal"
type GetValidEntries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends FooValue<any, any, K>
    ? T[K] // Keep the original if everything is fine
    : T[K] extends FooValue<infer A, infer B, any> // If it is a valid FooValue, but with a wrong main Key
      ? FooValue<A, B, K> // Replace the mainKey with the object key
      : FooValue<any, any, K>; // Invalid FooValue
};

function accept<T extends TValid, TValid = GetValidEntries<T>>(input: T) {
  console.log(input);
}

accept({
  key1: { first: "text1", second: 1, mainKey: "key1" },
  key2: { first: 2, second: "text2", mainKey: "key2" },
});
```

**Edit:**

Your solution could also work. You just need to better constraint the type in the `accept` function. (as described in the original answer)

- this approach also gives decent error messages by default

Keep in mind though, that this approach will not error, if the users forget the `as const` assertion in the function argument. Which may not be the behavior you are looking for.

This happens because we force the `Key` to be the same type as `mainKey` with the `as T[Key]["mainKey"]`. This will work even if the type was `string` (which is the default that TS will infer from an object literal).

```js
interface FooValue<A, B> {
  mainKey: string;
  first: A;
  second: B;
}

type FooValueObj = {
  [key: string]: FooValue<unknown, unknown>;
};

type FooConfig<T extends FooValueObj> = {
  [Key in keyof T as T[Key]["mainKey"]]: T[Key];
};

function accept<T extends TValid, TValid extends FooValueObj = FooConfig<T>>(
  input: T,
) {
  console.log(input);
}

accept({
  key1: { first: "text", second: 1, mainKey: "key1" },
  key2: { first: 2, second: "text2", mainKey: "key2" },
  // As const is required, because otherwise the type of the object will
  // be simplified by typescript and the validation wouldn't be possible
  // (this is the asterist *)
} as const);
```

**Original:**

Doing what you want to do is possible, however only with a big asterisk (*)

**The solution:**

```js
interface FooValue<A, B, Key = string> {
  mainKey: Key;
  first: A;
  second: B;
}

// Map over T if for a given key K => K != T[K].mainKey
// replace that value with "object key and value of mainKey must be equal"
// NOTE: Feel free to use `never` type but then the error message won't tell the user
// what's going wrong, and they will need to parse the typescript behind this function
type GetValidEntries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends FooValue<any, any, K>
    ? T[K]
    : "object key and value of mainKey must be equal";
};

function accept<T extends TValid, TValid = GetValidEntries<T>>(input: T) {
  console.log(input);
}

accept({
  key1: { first: "text1", second: 1, mainKey: "key1" },
  key2: { first: 2, second: "text2", mainKey: "key2" },
  // As const is required, because otherwise the type of the object will
  // be simplified by typescript and the validation wouldn't be possible
  // (this is the asterist *)
} as const);
```

**Explanation:**

The secret sauce of this solution is the generic parameter of the `accept` function. This is a trick you can use to perform custom validation on the generic parameters, but you lose any good error messages, so you'll need to do  the work around with the string literal as an error message.

The essence of the work around, is that the values for generic parameters are assigned before the `extends` constraints are checked. Therefore, we can use the helper `TValid` generic parameter, to validate the first parameter `T`

If you are interested in a more comprehensive explanation, you can checkout my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77965184/limit-argument-types-for-guard-function/77979042#77979042).

Comment: Wow, that is a good strategy, essentially we are forcing TS resolve GetValidEntries<T> first with T -> is type of input and then we are checking if T extends GetValidEntries<typeof input>. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Also @juraj do you know why the `as T[Key]['mainKey']` doesn't work here ?

Comment: @AnubhavGupta actually, when I think about it, you could use that as well. Just replace the `GetValidEntries` type with your `FooConfig` and make sure to put `TValid extends FooValueObj`. This will give you decent error messages by default as well. I will edit the answer to include this solution. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks @juraj, yes it seems like with `as T[Key]["mainKey"]`, we need to add an extra type of  
```type FooValueObj = {
  [key: string]: FooValue<unknown, unknown>;
};
``` which seems unnecessary with your latest approach.

Comment: found a shorter way:


```type GetValidEntries<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]:  T[K] extends FooValue<infer A, infer B> ? FooValue<A, B, K> : never
};

function accept<T extends GetValidEntries<T>>(input: T) {
    return input;
}```

Comment: The only thing that is not clear is why this doesn't work 
```function accept<T>(input: GetValidEntries<T>) {
    return input;
}```

Comment: For typescript to be able to infer the generic argument `T` from the value you pass in, it has to be used as `T` itself, not `GetValidEntries<T>`